# Use webpack with angular4, typescript2, the lines of sourcemaps are not match with source code

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webpack, visual-studio-code

all.

I got a confusion about sourcemap of angular4 with webpack.

Using VSCode installing the [Chrome Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) debug my codes.

I defined a method in a component to deal with `click` event.

When I launch a chrome by debugger mode in VSCode, I can create a breakpoint, but the problem is the lines do not match between sourced codes by sourcemap and original codes in editor tool.

These are screenshot:

Original codes

[image]

Sourced codes:

[image]

If I create the breakpoint at line:14 or 15, the process cannot be break; but if create at line:16, it can be.

So how can I solve this line not matching problem?